# Set up environment for React Native using Expo Cli

Tags: expo

I am trying to set up the environment for React Native using Expo Cli.

However, I received the following errors:

> ```
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-18T09_46_48_810Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Did you try install with yarn and post the log

Comment: yarn global add expo-cli

Comment: yarn: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable